# programming android in android studio 3.1

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a beginner at programming I have just started learning android in course I want to implement some code but does not work
my code about creating an intent: is there something wrong

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main):
    Button mybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button)
    myButtton SetClickListener(new ViewOnClicklistner)
}
override public fun OneClick (view) {
  val i: Any = log.i(ça marche)
```

Comment: That doesn't look like Java. Please [edit] your question to add a tag for the right language. Also `OneClick` feels like it is a typo.

Comment: sorry i dont know witch language am beginner please if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to programming, you'll be better off going through something like this: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app-kotlin/index.html#0

But for your snippet, go with something like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val myButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
    myButton.setOnClickListener { v -> Log.i("Tag Name", "This is what I'm logging.") }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to fire a Button so it implements some code first I will show you the XML file for the Button btnListen and it has a onClick method called onLISTEN

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnListen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:onClick="onLISTEN"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="LISTEN"
    android:textColor="@color/color_Purple"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

OK not the two ways to make this Button do some thing

```
class PageThreeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_three)

    val btnListen = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnListen)
    btnListen.setOnClickListener() {
        Toast.makeText(this@PageThreeActivity, "This is a Toast Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}// end onCreate

fun onLISTEN(view: View) {

    val intent = Intent(this@PageThreeActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

}// end of Class

If you are starting out this is Kotlin code no Java 
also you might look at marking the end of the closing curlier brace for end of Class and the end onCreate. It is nice to learn about onClickListeneres in Kotlin we prefer the onClick method and develop a naming convention. WHY? Less code

Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score -1):

use this code --

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Button button=findViewById(R.id.btn);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

//-write your event 
    }
});

    }
}
```

Comment: Question is in Kotlin. questioner may not understand java.